# VuetifyLoaderPlugin Error No matching rule for vue-loader found

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, yarnpkg, vue-loader, vuetify-loader

Im trying to install the vuetify but it is giving me this Error:

```
[VuetifyLoaderPlugin Error] No matching rule for vue-loader found.
Make sure there is at least one root-level rule that uses vue-loader and VuetifyLoaderPlugin is applied after VueLoaderPlugin.
```

The package.json:

```
{
 "name": "vueapp",
 "version": "0.1.0",
 "private": true,

"scripts": {

    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },

  "dependencies": {

    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vuetify": "^2.4.0"
  },

  "devDependencies": {

    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
    "sass": "~1.32.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.4.1",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.7.0"
        
  },

  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

I am using Vue version 6.14.13, @vue/cli 4.5.13 and yarn version 1.22.10. I've tried to change the dependencies in package.json but it doesn't seem to work.

[image: error]

Comment: There is no Vue version 6.14.13. Your `package.json` shows Vue 3.

Comment: thank you! i have decided to use Vue 2 instead because I read that there are apparently some problems using vuetify with Vue 3

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue.
I removed   "vuetify-loader": "^1.7.0" from devDependancies and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In webpack.mix.js change this :

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css').sourceMaps();
```

into this :

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue().sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css').sourceMaps();
```

Answer (score 0):

I also suffered from the same error.
However, after a lot of trouble, the best answer is to recreate the foundation of your application with the "yarn create nuxt-app" command. Then overwrite the required source. nuxt.config.js may need to carefully merge the settings.